# Find if a specific (max) value is repeated in a row

Tags: python, pandas

For a dataframe as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4),
              (1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
              (1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1)],
            columns=['P'+str(i+1) for i in range(9)],
            index = ['row1', 'row2', 'row3'])
```

Resultant df:

```
        P1  P2  P3  P4  P5  P6  P7  P8  P9
row1    1   2   3   4   0   1   2   3   4
row2    1   2   0   1   2   3   4   5   6
row3    1   2   3   0   1   2   3   0   1
```

I want to find if a row has the max value occuring more than once, e.g.

```
 df.max(axis=1)
 >>> row1    4
     row2    6
 >>> row3    3
```

With `row1` and `row3` having their max value repeated.

Ideally, the solution is vectorised as I have 40,000 rows and 50 columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) for comapring and count `True`s by [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html), last filter indices by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
a = df.eq(df.max(axis=1),axis=0).sum(axis=1)
print (a)
row1    2
row2    1
row3    2
dtype: int64

b = a.index[a > 1]
print (b)
Index(['row1', 'row3'], dtype='object')
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.eq(df.max(axis=1),axis=0))
         P1     P2     P3     P4     P5     P6     P7     P8     P9
row1  False  False  False   True  False  False  False  False   True
row2  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False   True
row3  False  False   True  False  False  False   True  False  False
```

**Numpy** alternative:

```
arr = df.values
c = (arr == arr.max(axis=1)[:, None]).sum(axis=1)
print (c)
[2 1 2]

a = pd.Series(c, index=df.index)
print (a)
row1    2
row2    1
row3    2
dtype: int32
```

Comment: Why do we need to use `df.eq( ***, axis=0)`? What does `axis=1`  check?

Comment: If use `axis=1` it check per columns, but you need check by indices, so use `axis=0`.  for check with `axis=1` is possible use `df.eq(df.max(axis=0), axis=1)` - it compare each column by max.